# Possible reason for Lower Test Accuracy but high AUC score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Lets say I have a dataset like below:

```
word    label_numeric
0   active  0
1   adventurous 0
2   aggressive  0
3   aggressively    0
4   ambitious   0
```

I use a word2Vec trained model and convert each word into their word vector of 300 dimensions. This is how it looks now.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 label
0   0.058594    -0.016235   -0.174805   0.072266    -0.201172   0.073242    -0.074219   -0.149414   0.245117    -0.050049   -0.016357   -0.147461   -0.003311   0.071289    -0.008545   -0.179688   0.001686    -0.009949   -0.036621   0.048096    -0.033447   0.105957    -0.490234   0.249023    -0.199219   -0.025635   -0.248047   0.136719    -0.068848   -0.320312   0.259766    -0.053223   0.154297    -0.050537   0.110840    0.027100    0.000412    -0.133789   0.077148    0.058838    0.230469    -0.033203   -0.179688   -0.125977   -0.166992   -0.110352   -0.365234   -0.330078   -0.021729   -0.076660   0.124023    -0.107910   -0.051758   0.127930    0.192383    0.025024    0.033691    -0.386719   -0.006195   -0.074219   -0.175781   -0.088379   -0.341797   0.145508    -0.051758   0.099609    0.020874    -0.042969   -0.145508   0.090332    0.096191    0.061768    0.209961    0.314453    -0.080078   -0.304688   0.238281    -0.060791   0.146484    0.041504    -0.113281   0.019409    0.328125    0.300781    -0.153320   -0.174805   -0.347656   -0.002167   0.115723    0.104004    0.012817    -0.175781   0.088867    -0.291016   -0.092773   0.144531    -0.006256   -0.066406   -0.145508   -0.182617   -0.144531   0.074707    -0.157227   -0.025513   -0.013977   -0.289062   0.051514    -0.010559   0.121582    0.072754    0.005188    -0.162109   -0.246094   0.002014    -0.072266   -0.026733   0.143555    0.067383    0.398438    -0.212891   0.029663    -0.041748   -0.005157   0.337891    -0.192383   -0.135742   0.226562    -0.033691   -0.188477   0.322266    0.136719    -0.058594   -0.068359   0.136719    0.029175    -0.152344   -0.086426   0.021729    -0.005524   0.115723    0.106445    0.257812    0.000546    -0.161133   -0.046875   -0.049805   -0.058594   -0.110840   0.029907    -0.322266   -0.032715   -0.136719   -0.148438   0.125977    -0.205078   0.027222    -0.005219   -0.188477   0.318359    0.002792    0.155273    0.261719    -0.043457   0.113281    0.142578    0.170898    -0.202148   0.028687    0.239258    0.033203    -0.330078   -0.003647   -0.054199   -0.142578   0.201172    0.053467    -0.249023   -0.180664   0.147461    -0.036865   -0.015259   -0.107910   -0.134766   0.052002    0.109863    0.067871    0.022705    0.058838    -0.189453   -0.093262   -0.043945   -0.009216   0.020386    -0.232422   -0.083008   0.062500    0.016479    0.033936    0.041016    0.049805    0.071289    0.076660    -0.003937   -0.261719   -0.198242   -0.269531   -0.035889   -0.249023   -0.023071   -0.091797   -0.093750   0.192383    -0.376953   0.170898    0.027832    0.023438    0.047363    -0.051270   0.020386    -0.029663   0.128906    0.044434    -0.199219   0.060547    0.138672    0.104980    0.314453    -0.125000   -0.075684   0.088379    0.109863    -0.058594   0.063477    -0.120117   -0.177734   0.017700    0.112793    -0.161133   -0.188477   -0.102051   -0.068848   -0.073730   0.168945    -0.042236   -0.024536   0.128906    -0.066406   -0.020996   0.087891    -0.224609   0.025146    -0.054932   -0.102539   -0.020142   0.123047    -0.171875   0.195312    -0.203125   -0.265625   -0.026367   0.154297    -0.235352   0.092773    0.032715    0.177734    0.063477    -0.168945   0.153320    -0.182617   0.101074    0.074219    0.031250    -0.038086   0.037598    0.035400    -0.150391   -0.108398   -0.071289   -0.080078   0.078613    0.022705    0.148438    -0.098633   -0.032471   0.083984    0.031494    -0.052002   -0.062988   0.316406    -0.105957   0.026733    0.018921    0.026855    -0.176758   -0.088379   0.127930    -0.104980   0.206055    -0.003296   0.184570    0
1   -0.068359   0.076660    -0.224609   0.292969    0.054688    -0.069824   0.028809    0.090332    -0.160156   0.080566    0.289062    -0.005615   0.074219    -0.071289   0.069824    0.032715    -0.036133   0.043457    0.084961    0.224609    -0.001160   0.100098    -0.090820   0.209961    0.101074    0.009949    0.038818    0.151367    0.209961    -0.157227   0.118652    0.247070    0.090332    0.244141    0.125000    -0.253906   0.204102    -0.234375   0.118652    -0.000603   0.253906    -0.146484   -0.077148   0.180664    -0.110840   0.018677    -0.113770   0.159180    0.245117    -0.033447   -0.041748   0.246094    0.018677    0.034180    0.103516    0.087891    0.339844    -0.357422   -0.230469   -0.051758   -0.038574   -0.281250   -0.218750   -0.210938   -0.150391   -0.040283   -0.049072   -0.292969   0.151367    0.143555    0.048340    -0.194336   -0.027344   0.038574    -0.086426   -0.003036   -0.095215   0.062500    -0.098145   0.085938    -0.099609   0.046875    0.039551    0.182617    -0.142578   0.189453    -0.261719   0.030273    0.056152    0.123535    -0.082520   -0.075684   -0.267578   0.014832    0.047852    -0.012451   0.131836    0.240234    -0.107910   -0.316406   0.081055    0.092285    0.014771    0.211914    0.062500    -0.143555   0.412109    -0.210938   -0.064453   -0.193359   0.051025    0.027954    0.026367    -0.109375   0.020752    -0.124512   0.198242    -0.105469   0.250000    -0.071289   -0.065430   -0.139648   -0.032959   0.386719    -0.185547   -0.166992   0.036621    0.001389    -0.090820   0.030396    -0.249023   -0.047363   -0.013245   0.318359    -0.150391   0.048340    -0.037354   0.125000    -0.053711   0.562500    0.005463    -0.067383   -0.345703   0.214844    0.044678    0.170898    -0.218750   0.243164    -0.165039   -0.259766   -0.158203   -0.275391   -0.138672   0.080566    -0.212891   -0.238281   -0.075684   0.015320    0.089844    -0.052490   0.031738    0.339844    0.035400    0.212891    0.127930    -0.033447   0.234375    0.130859    -0.209961   -0.106445   -0.236328   0.047607    -0.153320   -0.075195   0.048340    0.133789    -0.085449   0.122070    -0.187500   -0.172852   -0.137695   -0.392578   -0.028809   -0.177734   -0.131836   -0.141602   0.071777    -0.118652   -0.072754   -0.081543   -0.070312   0.033447    0.124023    -0.088379   -0.130859   0.131836    -0.010437   0.247070    -0.287109   0.077637    0.033203    0.032959    -0.136719   -0.079590   0.051758    -0.045898   -0.131836   -0.326172   -0.202148   -0.033203   -0.176758   0.180664    -0.148438   0.227539    -0.212891   -0.143555   0.273438    0.134766    -0.261719   0.073242    -0.054688   0.027466    0.126953    0.234375    0.097168    0.259766    0.253906    -0.170898   -0.189453   0.239258    -0.173828   0.024536    0.002090    0.101074    0.351562    0.174805    0.162109    -0.146484   -0.103516   -0.037354   0.065430    -0.104004   0.108398    0.296875    0.172852    0.078613    -0.209961   -0.133789   0.037354    -0.125977   0.172852    -0.102539   0.034424    0.095215    0.158203    -0.291016   -0.047852   -0.161133   -0.024414   -0.162109   -0.161133   0.109375    0.003372    0.218750    -0.022339   0.057861    -0.351562   -0.113770   -0.247070   -0.108398   0.097656    0.083008    0.357422    0.347656    0.341797    -0.031006   0.056885    0.114746    0.083008    0.192383    0.335938    0.154297    -0.244141   -0.445312   0.166992    0.396484    -0.132812   0.077148    -0.108398   0.131836    0.063477    0.001221    -0.219727   -0.062988   -0.137695   -0.133789   0.223633    -0.069336   0.163086    0.236328    0
2   -0.003067   0.219727    -0.082520   0.255859    -0.209961   -0.117188   0.109863    0.107422    0.059570    0.007233    0.059082    -0.152344   0.208984    -0.095703   -0.096680   -0.312500   -0.154297   0.024780    0.032471    0.250000    0.090820    0.017944    0.105957    0.133789    -0.122070   0.199219    -0.073730   -0.142578   0.203125    0.047607    0.222656    0.019531    0.026123    -0.138672   0.061768    0.120605    -0.008789   -0.047852   0.269531    -0.182617   0.566406    -0.218750   -0.043457   -0.051270   -0.273438   -0.084961   -0.240234   -0.158203   0.221680    -0.043457   0.308594    0.221680    -0.112305   -0.014343   0.070312    0.174805    -0.090332   -0.384766   0.003281    -0.002808   -0.273438   -0.116211   -0.542969   -0.008057   -0.137695   0.209961    0.231445    -0.008484   -0.092285   0.226562    -0.021851   -0.083984   0.069336    0.277344    -0.217773   0.057129    0.269531    0.218750    0.137695    0.093750    -0.101562   0.281250    0.029785    0.126953    0.066406    -0.019775   -0.287109   0.267578    0.195312    -0.135742   0.012207    0.048828    -0.237305   0.101562    0.206055    -0.091309   -0.085938   0.112305    -0.008423   -0.037109   0.099121    0.018433    -0.108398   0.031982    0.202148    -0.273438   -0.007874   -0.179688   0.025879    -0.046387   -0.172852   -0.202148   -0.086426   -0.028564   -0.033447   -0.047852   0.184570    -0.146484   0.109863    -0.243164   -0.251953   -0.000456   -0.073730   0.199219    -0.248047   -0.265625   0.261719    0.003693    0.092285    -0.111816   -0.118652   -0.320312   0.121582    0.127930    -0.127930   -0.087402   0.229492    0.040527    -0.121094   0.233398    0.052734    0.213867    -0.111328   -0.030884   -0.084961   0.054932    -0.068848   0.133789    -0.121582   -0.235352   -0.031982   0.062500    -0.137695   0.244141    -0.070312   -0.090820   -0.050781   0.041748    0.166992    0.200195    0.016724    0.292969    0.023682    -0.232422   -0.113281   -0.032959   0.038330    -0.357422   0.187500    -0.034180   -0.157227   -0.213867   0.007233    0.136719    0.018433    0.040771    0.089355    0.162109    -0.051514   -0.109863   -0.142578   -0.292969   -0.043945   0.200195    -0.079102   -0.007172   0.131836    0.206055    -0.125977   -0.092285   0.118652    -0.042236   -0.054443   -0.082520   -0.238281   -0.078125   0.052979    0.003601    -0.045166   0.126953    0.064453    0.296875    0.145508    -0.006378   0.015869    -0.070312   0.036377    -0.277344   0.038574    -0.112793   -0.224609   0.171875    -0.184570   0.062500    0.142578    -0.170898   0.189453    -0.067871   -0.239258   -0.110840   -0.043213   0.089844    0.069824    0.012512    0.162109    -0.194336   0.419922    -0.116699   0.170898    0.119141    -0.189453   0.102051    0.055420    0.026245    0.008545    0.052246    -0.088379   -0.236328   -0.041016   -0.125000   -0.051514   0.020020    0.051758    -0.137695   0.206055    -0.029297   -0.106445   -0.039062   0.285156    -0.018677   0.265625    -0.072266   -0.090820   -0.030640   -0.112793   -0.181641   -0.000690   -0.171875   -0.115234   -0.179688   0.114746    0.032227    -0.016235   -0.063477   0.054688    -0.033691   -0.242188   -0.292969   -0.229492   0.067871    0.006378    0.345703    0.024780    0.148438    0.119629    0.121582    0.024780    0.086914    0.066895    0.181641    0.120605    0.234375    0.034180    -0.306641   -0.124512   0.145508    0.025269    -0.138672   0.353516    -0.227539   -0.082520   -0.035645   0.066895    -0.085938   -0.159180   -0.087402   0.186523    0.289062    -0.075195   0.050781    0
In [223]:
```

I have two labels 0 and 1. I am now doing a Binary classification with 300 dimension word vectors as features.

Here is the details of training and testing count:

```
# Splitting the dataset to train test
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
train_X, test_X,train_Y,test_Y = train_test_split(jpsa_X_norm,jpsa_Y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

print("Total Sample size in Training {}\n".format(train_X.shape[0]))
print("Total Sample size in Test {}".format(test_X.shape[0]))
​
​
Total Sample size in Training 151

Total Sample size in Test 65
```

Now my label ratio in training data is as below:

```
0    87
1    64
dtype: int64
```

So it's slightly imbalanced class dataset with ratio of 0:1=1:35

I now do a GridSearchCV for both SVM and Random Forest. In both the algo, i put

```
class_weights={1:1.35,0:1}
```

to take into account the class imbalance problem in machine learning.

Here is my GridSearchCV function:

```
def grid_search(self):

    """This function does Cross Validation using Grid Search

    """

    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    self.g_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=self.estimator,param_grid=self.param_grid,cv=5)
    self.g_cv.fit(self.train_X,self.train_Y)
```

I get the following as result for SVM.

```
The mean train scores are [ 0.57615906  0.57615906  0.57615906  0.57615906  0.93874475  0.57615906
  0.57615906  0.57615906  1.          0.94867633  0.57615906  0.57615906
  1.          1.          0.950343    0.57615906  0.81777921  0.99668044
  1.          1.        ]

The mean validation scores are [ 0.57615894  0.57615894  0.57615894  0.57615894  0.87417219  0.57615894
  0.57615894  0.57615894  0.8807947   0.8807947   0.57615894  0.57615894
  0.86754967  0.87417219  0.88741722  0.57615894  0.70860927  0.90728477
  0.87417219  0.87417219]

The score on held out data is: 0.9072847682119205
 Parameters for Best Score : {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}

The accuracy of svm on test data is: 0.8769230769230769

Classification Metrics for svm :
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.87      0.92      0.89        37
          1       0.88      0.82      0.85        28

avg / total       0.88      0.88      0.88        65
```

The parameter grid for hyperparamter values passed to GridSearchCV for SVM is:

```
grid_svm=[{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-4],\
                     'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100]},\
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [0.1,1,10,100]}]
```

I ran Random Forest also:

Here is the result:

```
The mean train scores are [ 0.99009597  1.          0.99833333  1.          0.99833333  1.
  0.99834711  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.        ]

The mean validation scores are [ 0.79470199  0.85430464  0.8807947   0.87417219  0.8807947   0.85430464
  0.83443709  0.82781457  0.86754967  0.84768212  0.88741722  0.87417219
  0.81456954  0.86092715  0.85430464  0.83443709  0.8410596   0.8410596
  0.83443709  0.86092715  0.85430464  0.83443709  0.84768212  0.82781457
  0.82781457  0.82119205  0.85430464  0.81456954  0.82781457  0.85430464
  0.82781457  0.84768212  0.83443709  0.86092715  0.87417219  0.86754967
  0.86092715  0.86092715  0.8410596   0.86754967  0.86754967  0.8410596 ]

The score on held out data is: 0.8874172185430463
 Parameters for Best Score : {'max_depth': 4, 'n_estimators': 600}

The accuracy of rf on test data is: 0.8307692307692308

Classification Metrics for rf :
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.77      1.00      0.87        37
          1       1.00      0.61      0.76        28

avg / total       0.87      0.83      0.82        65
```

I had 42 combination of hyper parameter values for RF as below:

```
grid_rf={'n_estimators': [30,100,250,500,600,900], 'max_depth':[2,4,7,8,9,10,13]}
```

Now if you look at both the outputs for SVM and RF, my training accuracy is like close to 99% but test accuracy and validation accuracy is not close to training accuracy. This should suggest Overfitting, but I did the hyper parameter tuning using Grid Search and Random Forest generally doesn't overfit too.

So what could be causing this low test/validation accuracy?

Also the AUC  of both from ROC plot is very good close to 0.96. So AUC is good, and accuracy is bad I can understand class imbalance issue might be in play. But then I took care of that using class weights parameter in both. So then also my test and validation accuracy is not comparable to training?

[image]

Can this be because of less test data (65)?

Edit:

Here is how I did the standardization of features.

```
# Standardizing the data with zero mean and Unit standard deviation of each feature (columns)
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Getting the standardizing scaler to be used for any new data too
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(train_X_norm)
train_X_std=scaler.transform(train_X_norm)

## Using the same transformation fitted on training data to transform the test data. 
test_X_std=scaler.transform(test_X_norm)
```

I fit the standardizer on the training data only and then use that to transform the test data. One shouldnt be including the test data to calculate the standard deviation and mean of each feature as that would be cheating.

But even after doing this, my test accuracy falls below what I had for non standardized data. That is strange

Comment: Your training data size seems small given how many features you have.

Comment: Yeah thats the max I can have unfortunately. So what is happening here if training data is small? I mean i know its high dimensional problem but overfitting might be an issue then? I don't know if I should reduce features somehow... I mean, it's a word vector so I don't want to use some Feature Importance values and all. Or in SVM,?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem about overfitting.

Can your training set cover all situation? Actually, if you are using neural network to fit this classification problem, you can also get a perfect training result even though using random word embedding. But there is no relevance between training set and test set(real situation), so the test result will be as bad as random classification.

Your situation is similar. You randomly choose some samples as test sample, and leave the remains as training set. But could you ensure that every sample in your test set has relevant(similar) samples in your training set? Generally, the answer is NO, so the test result is usually lower than training result. The lower relevance, the lower test result will be.

Further, result in production will be also lower than test result, test set is just a simulation of production environment.

So don't worry about your program, it works fine.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to understand what you wrote. You are saying because the test distribution is not similar to training, hence the low result. Well here is the point. 

That is true what you are saying. But that makes more sense if both the data are from different distribution. Like if I train on one type of words and test of different type of words. Then the distribution of both type of words is different. Then it makes sense. 

But in my case, I have the same "type" of words in training and test. So I should assume the distribution is same. In that case there is some diff in score, not much

Comment: @Baktaawar First, there is an exist distribution where all your data comes from, including training set and test set, and let's named it as a vector space `R`. But notice, the samples you have are just __some__ points in R. The process of training is using training set to fit an artificial vector space `G` which is close to R. If you read some basic theory about ML, you will see `|Error(in sample) - Error(out sample)|` is positively  correlated with complexity of R and inversely correlated with the size of training set.

Comment: @Baktaawar Intuitively, training set and test set are surely extracted from the same distribution. But the model you fit from training set `G` is not close to `R`. Maybe close around the points in your training set, but not at other places.

Comment: @straw The theory you are quoting is called as Structural Risk Minimization in ML. I know about that. It's a function of your VC dimension (which is a measure of your complexity) and inversely related to training size. 

That I understand. But if your training and test are from the same distribution (not having this is called Sampling Bias in ML  (this is a must otherwise ML won't work), then as per the complexity graph, your validation/test error should mimic training error. <cont>

Comment: It's very good if they converge, but if not able to converge then there shouldn't be a lot of difference between training error and test error.

 Now I don't know if accuracy of 99% on training and 88% on test is large difference or is this ok to be considered fine? This is my question. 


Secondly, I tried standardizing the features to zero mean and unit sd. SVM works better with standardized features so I did that.  But it reduced my test accuracy compared to non standardized features shown above. That is weird.

Comment: @ Based on your training set(too small to represent the target space `R`), it's fine. To your second question, did you do the same process for your test set? I mean use the same function for every sample(for example: `for sample in training set + test set: sample = (sample - a) / b`). And then, the lower test accuracy you got can be just caused by  random noise.

Comment: Btw @sraw. I just saw your sample code. I don't think for doing standardization you would include the test sample too. You fit the standardizer on training data and then use that transformation on test data. 

Like in the EDIT i just put.